# Set case-sensitive collation in MySql from Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

By default Spring Boot (with JPA) creates columns with collation "latin1_swedish_ci".

Is possible to change this behavior from Spring configuration?
Because I have a unique constraint that fails because of this!

Comment: A workaround is creating a new schema with a case-sensitive charset, e.g. "latin1_general_cs", but it's not the real solution